# Jquery/Javascript cannot set property innerHTML with include a page html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I include a page html in other page. In the included page I have a element with an Id. I try change the element from the other page but I have a error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

Part.html

```
<h1 id="Title">Hello</h1>
```

Index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="PartDiv"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#PartDiv').load('/Part.html');
        });
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function funct1() {
            document.getElementById("Title").innerHTML = "Bye";
        }
        funct1();
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have a typo in your `getElementById` , your T is uppercase.

Comment: I changed the t but the error stay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple potential issues: first, your DOM element `id` is "title", not "Title". So your function should be:

```
function funct1() {
  document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = "Bye";
}
```

The next potential issue is that the jQuery `load` method is asynchronous, so you'll want to make sure you execute `funct1` function in the `load` callback to make sure the DOM element has been loaded fist:

```
$('#PartDiv').load('/Part.html', funct1);
```

Comment: $('#PartDiv').load('/Part.html', funct1); works well, thanks